# MySQL SSH Tunnel Breaking

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, openssh, autossh

I have autossh setup to make and reestablish a tunnel with a remote host. The application is MySQL.

There is a script which runs which checks local and remote tables and if there is a mismatch, it will pull new entries from the remote table into the local table.

My issue is, it also pulls blobs. Very large blobs. During blob transfer it will hang and stop transferring data. The only way to fix it is to kill the job and re-establish and restart the transfer.

Does anyone have any ideas of how better to improve this and make it transfer the blobs properly?

The data size is about 3 gigs. The connection is gigabit on our end.

Comment: you need to describe how you go about determining if there is a mismatch. Are both systems live for updates on their own merit, separately, from one another? You need details. Devil's in the Details.

Comment: Yes, both systems are always live for all the updates.There is an ssh tunnel that is always live. The behavior is it goes through all tables relatively easily, once it gets to the blobs tables, lets say there are 6000 blobs, it gets through 50 or 100 and then just stops and sits there and hangs. A way around it I found is, I have a cron job which runs every 30 minutes and checks if there are any processes active for the usr  account that the script runs under, grabs all the pids and kill them and then kick starts the process all over again. the blobs are mostly pdf files  if thats of any use.